# Using the try and try catch function on .WAV files

Tags: r, for-loop, try-catch, wav

Trying to cut a bunch of audio (.WAV) files into smaller samples in R. For this example, I'm using a loop to cut out 1 minute samples at 140 minutes.

For some files, the recording ends before 140 minutes due to an error in the recording device. When this occurs, an error appears -- and the loop stops. I'm trying to make it so the loop continues by using the try or tryCatch function however keep getting errors.

The code is as follows:

```
for(i in 1:length(AR_CD288)){
  CUT_AR288_5 <- try({readWave(AR_CD288[i], from = 140, to = 141, units = "minutes")})
  FILE.OUT_AR288_5<- sub("\\.wav$", "_140.wav", AR_CD288)
  OUT.PATH_AR288_5 <- file.path("New files", basename(FILE.OUT_AR288_5))
  writeWave(CUT_AR288_5, extensible=FALSE, filename = OUT.PATH_AR288_5[i])
  }
```

I get the following two errors from the code:

```
Error in readBin(con, int, n = N, size = bytes, signed = (bytes != 1),  : 
  invalid 'n' argument
Error in writeWave(CUT_AR288_5, extensible = FALSE, filename = OUT.PATH_AR288_5[i]) : 
  'object' needs to be of class 'Wave' or 'WaveMC
```

The loop still saves some samples into the "New files" directory, however, once the loop reaches a file <140 minutes, the loop stops.

I am very stuck! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Why do you use `try` only in the first line of the loop? Wrap the whole loop body in `try`.

Answer (score 0):

When I use `try`, I always do one (or both) of:

- check the return value to see if it inherits `"try-error"`, indicating that the command failed; or
- add `try(., silent = TRUE)`, indicating that I don't care if it succeeded (but this implies that I will not use its return value, either).

Try this:

```r
for (i in seq_along(AR_CD288)) {
  CUT_AR288_5 <- try({
    readWave(AR_CD288[i], from = 140, to = 141, units = "minutes")
  }, silent = TRUE)
  if (!inherits(CUT_AR288_5, "try_error")) {
    FILE.OUT_AR288_5 <- sub("\\.wav$", "_140.wav", AR_CD288)
    OUT.PATH_AR288_5 <- file.path("New files", basename(FILE.OUT_AR288_5))
    writeWave(CUT_AR288_5, extensible = FALSE, filename = OUT.PATH_AR288_5[i])
  }
}
```

Three notes:

1. I changed `1:length(.)` to `seq_along(.)`; the latter is more resilient in an automated use when it is feasible that the vector might be length 0. For example, if `AR_CD288` can ever be length 2, intuitively we expect `1:length(AR_CD288)` to return nothing so that the `for` loop will not run; unfortunately, it resolves to `1:0` which returns a vector of length 2, which will often fail (based on whatever code is operating in the loop). The use of `seq_along(.)` will always return a vector of length 0 with an empty input, which is what we need. (Alternatively and equivalent, `seq_len(length(AR_CD288))`, though that's really what `seq_along` is intended to do.)

- If you do not add `silent=TRUE` (or explicitly add `silent=FALSE`), then you will get an error message indicating that the command failed. Unfortunately, the error message may not indicate which `i` failed, so you may be left in the dark as far as fixing or removing the errant file. You may prefer to add an `else` to the `if (inherits(.,"try-error"))` clause so that you can provide a clearer error, such as

  ```r
    if (inherits(CUT_AR288_5, "try_error")) {
      warning("'readWave' failed on ", sQuote(AR_CD288[i]), call. = FALSE)
    } else {
      FILE.OUT_AR288_5 <- sub("\\.wav$", "_140.wav", AR_CD288)
      # ...
    }
  ```

  (noting that I put the "things worked" code in the `else` clause here ... I find it odd to do `if (!...) {} else {}`, seems like a double-negation :-).
- The choice to wrap one function or the whole block depends on your needs: I tend to prefer to know exactly where things fail, so the will-possibly-fail functions are often individually wrapped with `try` so that I can react (or log/message) accordingly. If you don't need that resolution of error-detection, then you can certainly wrap the whole code-block in a sense:

  ```r
  for (i in seq_along(AR_CD288)) {
    ret <- try({
      CUT_AR288_5 <- readWave(AR_CD288[i], from = 140, to = 141, units = "minutes")
      FILE.OUT_AR288_5 <- sub("\\.wav$", "_140.wav", AR_CD288)
      OUT.PATH_AR288_5 <- file.path("New files", basename(FILE.OUT_AR288_5))
      writeWave(CUT_AR288_5, extensible = FALSE, filename = OUT.PATH_AR288_5[i])
    }, silent = TRUE)
    if (inherits(ret, "try-error")) {
      # do or log something
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: This is great thank you! The code still won't run if I don't wrap the whole block. But when I wrap the whole block it works perfectly :)